# belongsTo does not work in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

In my app I have Users and Tickets.

In the table 'tickets' I have one foreign key, like this:

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

In the model 'Ticket' I have this relationship:

```
public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

User model:

```
public function createdTickets()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Ticket');
}
```

By doing this:

```
dd(\Auth::user()->createdTickets()->get()->toArray());
```

I get all tickets, no problem here. But when I try to get the owner from the Ticket, it gives me null:

```
$ticket = \Auth::user()->createdTickets()->first();
dd($ticket->owner); //if I try dd($ticket) it juts fine.
```

PS: For the record, I have another type of relationship between both model (many to many)

Ticket:

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimeStamps();
}
```

User:

```
public function followingTickets()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ticket')->withTimeStamps();
}
```

Comment: should you not call that owner as a function `$ticket->owner()`, or is this magically resolved by Laravel?

Comment: If i do $ticket->owner() laravel allows me to do things like $ticket->owner()->first(), $ticket->owner()->where() etc.. By doing $ticket->owner, laravel should give me a Collection object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer on laracasts forums:

[Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/belongsto-does-not-work#)

for "belongsTo" relation eloquent uses the method name on the foreign key. I am using `owner()`, so eloquent was looking for `owner_id` field.

So I had to do this:

```
public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```